# Open sourced library on video analysis and key frame extraction

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, video, python

I am new in multimedia analysis area.

I am working on a project which is built on **AngularJS** and **Flask** framework and I want to realize the following functions in our website:

- user can cut the video into segments and the website can merge all
  the selected segments into one new video;
- the website can extract key frames of the new video which is
  generated by the first step;
- the player can get a 'start time' parameter and a 'end time'
  parameter (or a 'duration' parameter) given by user and play the
  clips based on the user input parameters.

For now, I have searched several tools like **JWPlayer**, **FFMpeg**. But I really have no idea on how to use them and whether they are the best tools for these requirements. I was wondering if you might be able to give me some advice.

*[Update on 2015 Dec 10]*

I have made a progress bar by JavaScript and it can satisfied the 3rd requirement, so the video analysis part becomes the toughest one. I also find some other tools or libraries like **Video.js**, **OpenCV**, **VLC** etc. Can anyone give some advice on open source video analysis tools? It would be better if it works well with Python server.

Any advices, suggestions or tutorials are welcome~

Thank you.